# Count of notifications CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation will return?

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, cloudkit

If there is a lot of unread `CKNotification` I would do a 'full update', remove all local records, and download them again and set change token based previous change token == nil. But to do this I need to know wether it is worth to do.

Any way to check count of unread `CKNotification`?

Comment: That would be nice, but i'm afraid there is only the operation.moreComing and you won't know until that returns false.

Comment: then I might make an inference from the previous date when app was launched